Is there a plugin to plot txt files for Quick Look?
I have a bunch of data files that are .txt files that I would like to be able to view as plots via Quick Look. Is there a plugin (or other easy way, e.g., a setting, .etc) to do this? The values are all tab-delimited and one-dimensional, so it might not be too hard to code something that can do this, but I am probably overlooking something trivial.

If you're not averse to using the Terminal, there are several competent open source programs that will do this. First on the list is gnuplot, but there are many others.

Do you mean you want a plug--in that converts the numbers into an image? Also, are these actually ".txt" files? Any plug-in would have to control ALL files of that type, so every .txt file would be dealt with by this plug-in.

Benwiggy-- that's what I was thinking too. They are indeed .txt files but maybe I can tweak my DAQ program to save them as .csv or something else.

Seamus -- Thank you for the response, I'll check these out.

A heads-up: You need to add the @ symbol in front of the username... otherwise, that username gets no notification. See the Help link on the right-hand-side of the comment box for more details.

Are you planning to code this quicklook extension yourself? I doubt there is an existing plug-in that would do this (presumably you've searched).
